# c# how to dynamically call method on existing object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am calling an API and want to dynamically call methods from that object. Using ASP.Net reflections, it seems that it allows you to get the type of that object, then invoke. But that seems to call the method from an empty instance of that class. In my case I have that object with data/information in an existing instance of that class, so is it possible to call a method dynamically from it?

For example:

I have ServiceReference "ThirdPartyRef".

```
ThirdPartyRef.ThirdPartyRefApiClient api = new ThirdPartyRef.ThirdPartyRefApiClient();
ThirdPartyRef.ApiObjectCollection collection = new ThirdPartyRef.ApiObjectCollection();

ThirdPartyRef.GetOrderUpdatesCollections orderUpdates = new ThirdPartyRef.GetOrderUpdatesCollections();

collection = (ThirdPartyRef.ApiObjectCollection)api.get(orderUpdates);

foreach (ThirdPartyRef.Order orderUpdate in collection.Items)
{

    MethodInfo[] mi = orderUpdate.GetType().GetMethods();
    foreach (MethodInfo orderUpdateMethInfo in mi)
    {
        string methodName = orderUpdateMethInfo.Name.Replace("get_", ""); // for example get_LastModifiedDate and set_LastModifiedDate is available
        var meth = orderUpdate.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
        string result = string.Empty;
        result = meth.Invoke(orderUpdateMethInfo, null).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("result: " + result.ToString());
    }

}
```

I changed the actual name of the third party company for this example, hopefully I didn't make mistakes by re-typing the code.

When I run the code above, I just get empty outputs. So that made me believe that line that has "meth.Invoke" is being executed on an empty instance or a "type" of that object, not on the actual instance that has data.

When I directly call the method on that object, I'm able to see data.

```
Console.WriteLine("LastModified:" + orderUpdate.LastModified.ToString());
```

> Output - 
>   LastModified:8/3/2015 5:43:18 PM

Is there a way to dynamically call method on existing object? Or am I going about this all the wrong way? The reason I want to do it dynamically is because there are 40+ methods where I want to get that into a database. If I can just layout the database table to match, then it'll be easier in the long run if the third party company were to ever change their API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
result = meth.Invoke(orderUpdateMethInfo, null).ToString();
```

to this:

```
result = meth.Invoke(orderUpdate, null).ToString();
```

The first parameter of [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) is the object upon which you are acting, which should be your `orderUpdate` object as your show in the static code sample where you call `LastModified` directly.

Comment: I think your answer is right, it seems logical.

For some reason I keep getting an error when invoking the method. I guess I'll have to start a new thread..... When I go through each MethodInfo and get the names, I see:
set_LastModified
get_LastModified
set_Location
get_Location

but when i use visual studio's intellisense on that object "orderUpdate" I see the available methods: LastModified and Location. I don't see that get and set.

I've tried invoking "get_LastModified" and "LastModified" but each time I get: object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: FYI, i've replaced orderUpdateMethInfo with orderUpdate as you directed. Perhaps i'm onto the next problem. As replied above

Comment: @L.Le, what you are seeing is expected.  the `LastModified` and `Location` you are seeing are properties (I can tell by the code).  Under the hood, the CLR creates 2 methods with the get_ and set_ prefixes for properties, which you generally don't have to know, but it's very useful when doing Reflection.  Since you're having issues, what you're probably going to have to do is start using `Type.GetProperties` instead of `GetMethods`.

Comment: i was able to get it to work with your example now :) i think i was staring at the screen for 2-3 days working on the same project. so i didn't notice that the output actually worked.